# Only custom Y Grid AChartEngine

Tags: android, achartengine

Is there a way to only show the custom Y Grid

Since mRenderer.setSHowCustomTextGrid accepts only one parameter I don;t know how to set this.

How it is now:

[image]

How I want it:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added the APIs you need in SVN. You can download a version including this feature [here](https://repository-achartengine.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/org/achartengine/achartengine/1.2.0/).